# TensorFlow: How to get pointer to data contents of ConstTensor?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen

My team is working on developing a new backend for TensorFlow.  Generally, tensorflow opkernels are passed as arguments "Tensor" types which use memory allocated with our architecture:

```
void ComputeAsync(OpKernelContext* context, DoneCallback done) override {
  // Grab the input tensors
  const Tensor& A = context->input(0);
  const Tensor& B = context->input(1);

  // ...input validation...

  const our::Memory_Type *bA = static_cast<const our::Memory_Type *>(DMAHelper::base(&A));
  const our::Memory_Type *bB = static_cast<const our::Memory_Type *>(DMAHelper::base(&B));

  // ...additional preconditioning...

  // Create an output tensor
  Tensor *C = NULL;
  OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, out_shape, &C));
  our::Memory_Type *bC = static_cast<kpi::KPI_RMR_Mem*>(DMAHelper::base(C));

  //and run it
  our_impl(bA, bB, bC, done);
}
```

However, we are having more trouble with porting the "CrossOp" type, because part of the preconditioning involves converting the datatype to Eigen types:

```
// in0, in1, and output are all tensorflow::Tensor types, but ConstTensor is an Eigen type
typename TTypes<Type, 2>::ConstTensor in0_data =
    in0.flat_inner_dims<Type>();
typename TTypes<Type, 2>::ConstTensor in1_data =
    in1.flat_inner_dims<Type>();
typename TTypes<Type, 2>::Tensor output_data =
    output->flat_inner_dims<Type>();
```

`DMAHelper::base()` assumes it is run on a `Tensor` and not a `ConstTensor`.  Is it safe to follow the above operations with the ones below, or is does the process of `flat_inner_dims()` change the contents of the underlying data such that the result would be invalid or not read by TensorFlow?

```
const our::Memory_Type *in0_arg = static_cast<const our::Memory_Type *>(DMAHelper::base(&in0));
const our::Memory_Type *in1_arg = static_cast<const our::Memory_Type *>(DMAHelper::base(&in1));
const our::Memory_Type *output_arg = static_cast<const our::Memory_Type *>(DMAHelper::base(&output));

our_cross_impl(in0_arg, in1_arg, output_arg);
```